# Javascript Es6 sort array of objects fails to order

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects

```
       var unsorted = [
                    {id:1, score_on_kilo:15},
                    {id:2, score_on_kilo:18},
                    {id:3, score_on_kilo:3},
                    {id:4, score_on_kilo:100},
                ];

         var sorted = unsorted.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return parseInt(a.score_on_kilo) > parseInt(b.score_on_kilo);
                });
```

When i check on the `console.log(sorted)` an getting

```
[
 {id:1, score_on_kilo:15},
 {id:2, score_on_kilo:18},
 {id:3, score_on_kilo:3},
 {id:4, score_on_kilo:100},
]
```

What am i missing out as also on the sorted even changing to `return parseInt(a.score_on_kilo) - parseInt(b.score_on_kilo);` still doesnt sort the arrays

I expected this to have

```
[
 {id:4, score_on_kilo:100},
 {id:2, score_on_kilo:18},
 {id:1, score_on_kilo:15},
 {id:3, score_on_kilo:3},
]
```

What am i missing?

Comment: The `.sort()` callback function is supposed to return a *number*, not a boolean. In this case `a.score_on_kilo - b.score_on_kilo` would do it.

Comment: Using `parseInt(a.score_on_kilo) - parseInt(b.score_on_kilo)`, your code works perfectly fine for me and sorts from ID 3, 1, 2, then 4. It's important to use this form and not the `>` form, as the sort function need to return 0 only if the elements are equal, while yours will return false (coerced to 0) if A is less than B.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk true but it looks like the `parseInt()` is superfluous.

Comment: Otherway round if you want the biggest at the top, `b - a` not `a - b`

Comment: @Pointy It is definitely superfluous, but also won't matter or break this code, so it's irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a comment there suggested this would be what you want

```
unsorted.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseInt(b.score_on_kilo) - parseInt(a.score_on_kilo);
});
```

Since you are supposed to return a number